# Find the value of $a$ and $b$ if $x+1$ and $x−2$ are factors of $ax^3−4x^2+bx−12$

Tags: polynomials

> > **Find the value of $a$ and $b$ if $x+1$ and $x−2$ are factors of $ax^3−4x^2+bx−12$**

**Attemption**
$$
\begin{cases}
f(-1) = -a - b - 16\\
f(2) = 8a + 2b - 28
\end{cases}
$$
But then when I plug in $$b = 28 - 8a$$.
Then I get $$-a -(28- 8a) - 16=0$$$$a = 34/7$$

In the book it says $a = 10$ and $b = -26$. So I am stumped. Please help

Comment: It would be $2b=28-8a$.

Comment: So $ = - a - (14 - 4a) - 16 = 0 --> 3a - 30 = 0 --> 3a = 30 --> a = 10 $ Thank you

Comment: The system of equations is $ \ 8a + 2b \ = \ 28 \ $ and $ \ a + b \ = \ -16 \ $ .  Solving it by elimination works pretty directly.  [How late is it where you are?  Linear equations are too easy to mess up if you're sleepy... ;) ]

Comment: - 10 - b - 16 = 0 --> -b - 26 = 0 --> -b = 26 --> b = -26 (I am just posting working out)

Comment: @All: I merged to two duplicate copies of this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $(x+1)$ and $(x-2)$ are both factors of that polynomial so if we set $$f(x)=ax^3-4x^2+bx-12$$ so $$f(-1)=0=f(2)$$

---

If $f(-1)=0$ so $-a-4-b-12=0$ or $a+b=-16$. Also $f(2)=0$ so $8a-16+2b-12=0$ which yields $8a+2b=28$. From the first equation $a=-16-b$ and by plugging it into the second one we get $b=-26$. And so $a=10$.

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me could you please elaborate more.

Comment: @Orbit: Since, for example, `x−2` is a factor of `f(x)` so it means that when you set `x=2` into the polynomial, you get `0`.

Comment: I am seriously confused.

Comment: Do you know about functions and ways of factorizing polynomials with functions?If not so,then it might help us to know where you encountered the problem and what the chapter is about.

Comment: The chapter is titled 'Dividing Polynomials'. So you are say that f(2) = 0 So, f(2)= a(2)^3 - 4(2)^2 + b(2) - 12 --> 8a + 16 + 2b - 12 --> 8a + 2b + 4 = 0 --> 8a + b = -2 --> b = -2 - 8a

Comment: @Orbit: `x-2` is a factor of `f(x)`, so it means that for a some polynomial `p(x)` we have `f(x)=(x-2)p(x)`. Also, by the same story about `x+1` we get `f(x)=(x-2)(x+1)q(x)`. Now what is `f(2)`or `f(-1)`?

Comment: Could you just please give me the working out.

Comment: @Orbit,yes you are correct.If you then put in $x=-1$ in  the polynomial,you will get another equation and then you can solve for $a$ and $b$.As to why $f(2)=0$ and $f(-1)=0$,you might want to google Remainder-Factor Theorem,if you don't know it already.

Comment: I am not getting anything. The answer is a=10 and b=-26

Comment: @Orbit: Suppose $f(x)=(x+1)(x-2)g(x)$. Then $f(-1)=(0)(-3)g(-1)=0$; no matter what $g(-1)$ is, $f(-1)=0$. Furthermore, $f(2)=(3)(0)g(2)=0$; no matter what $g(2)$is, $f(2)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=ax^3 - 4x^2 + bx - 12=A(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$ where A is a constant and $(x-a),(x-b),(x-c)$ are factors of the polynomial.But,we already know that $(x+1)$ and $(x-2)$ are factors.Then,we can let $a=-1,b=2$ and get $$f(x)=ax^3 - 4x^2 + bx - 12=A(x+1)(x-2)(x-c)$$

$$f(-1)=a(-1)^3-4(1)^2+b(1)-12=A(-1+1)(-1-2)(-1-c)$$

$$\therefore -a-4-b-12=A\cdot0(-1-2)(-1-c)=0$$

Therefore,we have that $$-b-a-16=0.......(1)$$

Again,through similar reasoning, calculate $f(2)$

Now solve for $a$ and $b$.

You should probably check out the Remainder-Factor theorem.

Comment: This question has been answered thanks though

Comment: @rah4927: Thanks for that leading comment. :-) +1

Comment: @Orbit: more than one answer can be given to a question. Often different answers expose different aspects of a question, and lead to better understanding. rah4927 not only posted a good answer (in my opinion), but also gave helpful comments to B.S.'s answer. It seems to me that this answer deserves more than a seemingly dismissive, "This question has been answered thanks though"

Answer (score 1):

If   $p(x) / (x – a)  =  q(x)$  with remainder  $r(x)$,

then  $p(x)  =  (x – a)\cdot q(x)  +  r(x)$, right?

Since $(x+1)$ is a factor of your polynomial, $r(x)$ must equal to $0$, because a factor divides perfectly.

Thus we get $p(x)  =  (x+1)\cdot q(x) $

If we plug $x=-1$ in we get this:

$p(-1)  =  (-1+1)\cdot q(-1) = 0\cdot q(-1) = 0$

Likewise, $p(2)  =  (2-2)\cdot q(2) = 0\cdot q(2) = 0$

Answer (score 0):

You might have made a calculation error somewhere.
$$a+b = -16$$
$$2a+2b = -32$$
$$2b = -32-2a$$
Substitue this in the other equation that you have.
$$8a + 2b = 28$$
$$8a -2a - 32 = 28$$
$$6a = 60$$
$$a = 10$$
Substitute this in any of the $2$ equations and you get:
$$b = -26$$